# Django 3 Logging - custom app logger isn't used

Tags: django, logging

I have this app structure

```
app/
  customApp/
    urls.py
  app/
    settings.py
  manage.py
```

In settings.py this is my logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
    },
    'customApp': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    }
}
```

I am trying to trigger the customApp logger in customApp.urls like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse
from logging import getLogger

logger = getLogger(__name__)

def make_response(request):
    # if handler is set to console, print result is ALWAYS logged

    # this is the logging level hierarchy debug < info < warning < error
    logger.debug(f'DEBUG logged in {__name__}')
    logger.info(f'INFO logged in {__name__}')
    logger.warning(f'WARNING logged in {__name__}')
    logger.error(f'ERROR logged in {__name__}')
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Ok!</h1>')


urlpatterns = [
    path('', make_response)
]
```

When running the django app and going to this path is using the root logger, logging only the ERROR.

```
ERROR logged in customApp.urls
```

Why isn't my customApp logger being used?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing in `setting.py`, I usually create a new file `utils.py`

**utils.py**

```
import logging
from os import path

def setLogger():
    logger = logging.getLogger('myservice')
    BASE_DIR = path.dirname(path.dirname(__file__))
    LOG_DIR = path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myservice/logs/')
    hdlr = logging.FileHandler(LOG_DIR + 'myservice.log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return logger
```

Then in the views import it

**views.py**

```
from myservice.utils import setLogger
from traceback import format_exc

logger = setLogger()

def fn_login(req):
    try:
        pass
    except Exception as identifier:
        logger.error(format_exc())
        logger.info(format_exc())
        logger.warning(format_exc())
```